# Adding constraints programatically to custom components

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

I'm developing custom components in Swift by inheriting the default components. Below there is a piece of my code:

```
class DirectionButton: UIButton {
    var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        styleComponent()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        styleComponent()
    }

    func styleComponent() {
        backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "seta-proximo"))
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        let imageConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        backgroundImage.addConstraint(imageConstraints)
    }
}
```

The `backgroundImage` variable needs to be 10 points from the right part of the button, that's why I need the constraints.

After running I got an exception like that: The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint.

How can I add constraints correctly?

Comment: You can use anchor properties instead of nslayout constraint

Comment: Didn't figure out how to do that...

Comment: @AjayBeniwal See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

1. first do this :

> backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

1. Add constraint to **self** not **backgroundImage**
2. You are adding constraint from **self** to **self** (incorrect) add from **backroundImage** to **self**
3. Constraints are incomplete. You are adding only one trailing constraint.

Overall solution is this:

```
func styleComponent() {
       // Change clear.png with your own image name.

        backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "clear.png"))
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let imageConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundImage, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        self.addConstraint(imageConstraints)

        let topConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundImage, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        self.addConstraint(topConstraints)

        let bottomConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundImage, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        self.addConstraint(bottomConstraints)

        let leadingConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundImage, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        self.addConstraint(leadingConstraints)
}
```

The resultant output is this. You can modifiy the constants values to do according to your own will

[image]

In this case, The green is a Button and Red one is background image.

Try this and let me know if you are still getting any warning or complications.

Comment: I got the warning "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.". I cleared the button constraints in visual editor but the warning persists.

Comment: edit: add this: backgroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. Now the warning should go

Comment: the warning is still there and the image is in the position 0,0 of superview.

Comment: because the your constraint are both on self. Should'nt it be         let imageConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backgroundImage, attribute: .TrailingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

Comment: @chorajunior Edited the answer. Now its complete. Try this

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation, I followed the tip to use layout anchors as @AjayBeniwal suggested. The code I needed was the following (after I add the subview to the button):

```
backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).active = true
backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
backgroundImage.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.layoutMarginsGuide.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

This way, the image is vertically centralized to the button an 20 points far from the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

//Give Constrain Outlet to ImageView

```
func setConstrain()
{
self.imageConstrain.constant = -10
self.topConstraints.constant = 10
self.bottomConstraints.constant = -10
self.leadingConstraints.constant = 10
self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```